# How do I properly declare this as a function in Mathematica?

Tags: mathematica

I want to create a simple function that prints all prime numbers from 1 to x. I have the following code, which doesn't cause any errors from the kernel but it doesn't return anything:

```
allprimes[x_] = For[i=0, i<=x, i++, 
                     If[PrimeQ[i], Print[i]]]
```

What have I done wrong?

Comment: There is a Mathematica site in the stackexchange network.

Comment: How about `allPrimes[i_] := Select[Range[i], PrimeQ]`?

Comment: Typo..  use `:=` instead of `=` to define the function. Example: `f[x_] := x^2`